# how can i connect android application to mysql using jsp?

Tags: java, android

I want to use jsp rather than php. Is it by jdbc driver? And what are the steps.

```
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://<server>/<database>",
                    <username>,
                    <password>);

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT access_name, access_code FROM user_login");

            while (rs.next()) {
                x = rs.getString("access_name");
                y = rs.getString("access_code");
            }
```

This code gives me an exception like `ClassNotFoundException com.mysql.jdbc.driver`

Comment: You have to add mysql-connector to your classpath

Comment: You should visit this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107180/connect-android-to-mysql-using-jsp

Comment: @Jens will I add another System Variable 'ClassPath' or will I add it on 'Path'? Is that all that I need to do?

Comment: @Kirby You have to add to the classpath variable. PATH will not evaluated by java

Comment: @Jens Okay. Are there other things to do after setting the classpath?

Comment: @Kirby Classpath in tomcat is the <tomcat_home>/lib directory. Add the jar there and then restart the tomcat

Comment: @Jens I thought you're referring to 'System Variable'. I don't have Tomcat here in my desktop but I can access the database since the server was up . Do I need to install Tomcat locally for me to be able to use it on my Android development?

Answer (score 0):

You should download MySQL Connector from this link :
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html .

 Then just add it to your classpath.

Comment: I have mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin and I've tried to add it to classpath but still, it's ClassNotFoundException. Can you elaborate more of the steps so I can successfully connect the .jar file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right click your project in eclipse, build path -> add external jars.
Make sure that you copied the jar into apacheTomcat/lib .

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 2.1. I don't have Tomcat in my workstation but i can connect to the server that has Tomcat and .jar